# "Sollten Sie..." Questions

Tags: phrase, formality

Taken from a job description:

> Sollten Sie momentan nicht verfügbar sein, aber jemanden aus Ihrem Umfeld kennen?
>
> Sollten Sie an diesem Projekt interessiert sein, dann freuen wir uns auf ihre baldige Kontaktaufnahme!

In both these sentences there's a fragment *Sollten Sie*.

[Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Sollten%20Sie) does not provide me with any suggestions. There are only a few meanings as follows:

> You ought to...
> You should...
> You had better...

But these all are the beginnings of *declarative sentences*.

What could *Sollten Sie* mean when talking about questions?

Comment: The first example is likely not complete as it stands here.

Comment: @Emanuel I altered my question a bit. See edit. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm confused... I checked the edit but the first example is still the same :)

Comment: @Emanuel Oops, my apologies. Could you delete the bad example then? Is it "...dann freuen wir uns auf ihre baldige Kontaktaufnahme!" ? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's "Sollten Sie momentan..., aber jemanden aus Ihrem Umfeld?". The problem is the second part (after "aber") because it lacks subject and verb. "Jemanden aus ihrem Umfeld" is a direct object.

Comment: I'm not sure what the first example should convey, but you could fix it, for example, by changing "jemanden" to "jemand" or by adding "kennen" to the second clause. Then the sentence at least becomes grammatically correct. What is it what you want to say anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "in case". The construction is an omitted wenn-sentence.

> Hätte ich Hunger, würde ich essen.

is the same as

> Wenn ich Hunger hätte...

The "sollten" underlines the "conditionalness" while still leaving within the realm of possible and just generally polite.

> Wenn Sie an dem Job interessiert sind.... (rather straight-forward)
>   Wenn Sie an dem Job interessiert wären ... implies that you're not
>   Wenn Sie an dem Job interessiert sein sollten...

The last one is a nice mix of uncertainty and politeness but the structure isn't all that nice and so the "sollten" gets moved to the front.

> Sollten Sie interessiert sein...

You can roughly compare it to English sentences like

> In case you should have any questions...

Comment: Much easier: Sollten Sie interessiert sein -> Should you be interested.

Comment: @Robert... I wasn't sure whether it worked in English or not. I guess it does, then.  Anyway, since OP is from Belarus a more elaborate answer may have its merits

Answer (score 4):

Here, the *Konjunktiv II* of *„sollen“* is used to form a conditional clause:

> *„Sollten Sie etwas brauchen, rufen Sie mich bitte an.“*
>   (“Should you need anything, please call me.”)

It can be replaced by a conditional conjunction:

> *„Falls Sie etwas brauchen, rufen Sie mich bitte an.“*
>   (“If you need anything, please call me.”)